# One polymorphic association vs many through/HABTM associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a project that currently has tons of HABTM associations. Essentially, everything is related to everything else. I am considering setting up a single intermediate table/model that has two polymorphic fields. This way, if I add another model I can easily connect it to the remaining models. Is this a good idea? If not, why not? If it is, why don't all rails projects have this kind of intermediate table?

I see two other options. I could keep adding intermediate tables or I could add a table that contains one of each type. The former option is kind of a hassle and the latter option does not allow for self joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a polymorphic join table sounds like it would make things easier, I think you will end up creating more headache for yourself than it's worth.  Here are a few potential challenges/problems off the top of my head:

1. You will not be able to use ActiveRecord's **has_and_belongs_to_many** association or related helpers without a ton of hacking/monkeypatching which will immediately eclipse the time it would take to setup individual pairwise link tables.
2. Your join table will have two **id** columns, let's call them `a_id` and `b_id`.  For any given pair of models you will have to ensure that the ids always end up in the same column.

   Example: If you have two models called `User` and `Role`, you would have to ensure for that pair that the `user_id` is always stored in col `a_id` and the `role_id` is always stored in col `b_id`, otherwise you will not be able to index the table in any kind of meaningful way (and will run the risk of defining the same relationship twice).
3. If you ever want to use database enforcement of FOREIGN KEY constraints it is unlikely that this polymorphic link table scheme will be supported.
4. The universal link table will get **n times larger** than n separate link tables.  It shouldn't matter *much* with good indexing but as your application and data grow this could become a headache and limit some of your options in regards to scaling.  Give your DB a break.
5. Most or least importantly (I can't decide) you will be bucking the norm which means a lot fewer (if any) resources out there to help you when you run into trouble.  Basically the Adam Sandler "they're all gonna laugh at you" rationale.

#### Last thought: Can you eliminate any of the link tables by using `has_many :xxx, :through => :xxx` relationships?

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. Which of these reasons are not a problem for a single polymorphic join? #2? Seems to me that something like a generic intermediate table could make prototyping easier if rails handled it well.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but I think Rails only has built in support for one-to-many (belongs_to) polymorphic associations.  That would eliminate concerns #1, #2, and #5 and reduce the significance of 2 and 3.

Depending on your needs you may be able to move some of your many-to-many relationships to one-to-many if you make the decision to allow some data duplication. Example: An Address model which can belong to a Contact or a Customer.  With a many to many you can have assign the same address record to both, with one-to-many you could just duplicate it. Duplication can actually help scalability.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because I think it explains the current situation well. However, it seems like rails should handle this situation better.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking it all through, you could actually do this, but I wouldn't. Join tables grow fast enough as it is and i like to keep model relationships simple and easy to alter.
I'm used to working on very large systems / data sets though, so if you're going going to have much in each join then ok. I'd still do it separately for joins however and i really like my polymorphics.

Comment: i guess what i'm trying to say is, i think it would take far longer to set up the polymorphic stuff than to model a bunch more join tables

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be cleaner and more flexible if you were to use multiple join tables as opposed to one giant multipurpose join table.

Comment: If you had a `Category` model, and say `Article`, `Photo`, and  `Question` models that could be tagged with categories. A `Category` would always be half of the association.